# Killed worker when aggregating Dask data first over ID then on minutes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

My goal is to aggregate NYC Citibike data first over `station_id` then on minutes of `starttime` in Dask.

The head of the Dask DataFrame looks as follows,

```
df_start.head()
```

displays,

```
    starttime   start_station_name
start_station_id        
72  2017-08-15 16:02:02 W 52 St & 11 Ave
72  2017-12-01 09:52:20 W 52 St & 11 Ave
72  2017-09-06 12:39:25 W 52 St & 11 Ave
72  2016-05-26 08:41:24 W 52 St & 11 Ave
72  2016-02-28 14:57:16 W 52 St & 11 Ave
```

Aggregation in Dask,

```
count_per_station = df_start.groupby(
  ['start_station_id', 
   df_start.starttime.dt.year.rename('year'), 
   df_start.starttime.dt.month.rename('month'), 
   df_start.starttime.dt.hour.rename('hour'),
   df_start.starttime.dt.minute.rename('minute')]).count()

client.persist(count_per_station)
progress(count_per_station, notebook=False)
```

Gives the following output,

```
[########################################] | 100% Completed |  0.0s
```

Showing the head kills the worker,

```
count_per_station.head()
```

gives me a number of Nanny errors, WARNINGS of full garbage collector and ultimately fails with

```
KilledWorker: ("('dataframe-groupby-count-agg-dc00c500225feb4dc9e32c710613bd1c', 0)", 'tcp://127.0.0.1:49324')
```

Also tried to do the simple groupby in Dask and the difficult one in Pandas but getting an error there,

```
def min_counter(b):
    b.groupby([
      b.starttime.dt.year.rename('year'),           
      b.starttime.dt.month.rename('month'), 
      b.starttime.dt.hour.rename('hour'),    
      b.starttime.dt.minute.rename('min')]).count()

df_start.groupby(['start_station_id']).apply(min_counter)
```

leads to,

```
  /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bike-demand-forecasting/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:4: UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result
  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result
```

and again Garbage Collector warnings and ultimately a dead worker.

Ideally I would use the resample method in pandas but not sure how to use that or one of the above methods effectively without crashing the workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ends up being,

```
def min_counter(b):
    return b.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='starttime', freq='5min')).count()

counter_per_station = df_start.groupby('start_station_id').apply(min_counter)
```

hope this helps people facing the same issue.